# The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data in chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas, getimagedata

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':
The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data
```

I am getting above error only in chrome. My code(following) works fine in mozilla. I have not corss domain issue. So why could i get above error in chrome?

```
var wheel_canvas, wheel_context, can_w, can_h, wheel_grd;
var LARGE_RADIUS = 160;
var SMALL_RADIUS = 120;
var wheel_canvas = document.getElementById('wheel_canvas');
var wheel_context = wheel_canvas.getContext('2d');
var can_w = $(wheel_canvas).width();
var can_h = $(wheel_canvas).height();
var centerX = can_w / 2, centerY = can_h / 2;
var wheel_grd = null;
test('#FF0000');

function test(hex)
{
    $('#clrpicker').css({'left': 210, 'top': 210 });

    inverted = hexBW(hex);
    $('#color_val_show').val(hex);
    current_color_hex_val_selected = hex;
    $('#color_val_show').css({'color':inverted,'background':hex});

    fillGradientCirle(hex);
}

function fillGradientCirle(hex)
{
    wheel_context.rect(0, 0, can_w, can_h);
    wheel_grd = wheel_context.createLinearGradient(1, 1, 0, can_w, can_h);
    wheel_grd.addColorStop(1, '#ffffff');
    wheel_grd.addColorStop(0.5, hex);
    wheel_grd.addColorStop(0, '#000000');
    wheel_context.fillStyle = wheel_grd;
    wheel_context.beginPath();
    wheel_context.arc(centerX, centerY, LARGE_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    wheel_context.fill();
}

   $(wheel_canvas).click(function (e)
    {
        $.event.fix(e);         
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;

        can_p = $(this).offset();
        x = x - $(document).scrollLeft() - can_p.left;
        // Fixed typo
        y = y - $(document).scrollTop() - can_p.top;
        if (Math.sqrt((x - centerX) * (x - centerX) +  (y - centerY) * (y - centerY)) < SMALL_RADIUS) return; // Precaution
        $('#wheel_picker').css({ 'left': x-8 + 'px', 'top': y-8 + 'px' });
        var data = wheel_context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        pixelData = data;
        rgbString = 'rgb(' + pixelData[0] + ', ' + pixelData[1] + ', ' + pixelData[2] + ')';
        hex = rgb2hex(rgbString);

        inverted = hexBW(hex);
        $('#color_val_show').val(hex);
        current_color_hex_val_selected = hex;
        $('#color_val_show').css({'color':inverted,'background':hex});

        $('#feedback').html("Coordinates : " + x + "," + y + "  Color: " + hex);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all the code and you don't use any cross-origin images then the only error that stand out is this line:

```
wheel_grd = wheel_context.createLinearGradient(1, 1, 0, can_w, can_h);
```

This should only have [four arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) not five. The last argument may trip out Chrome in some way.

Try by changing it to:

```
//                                             x0 y0 x1     y1
wheel_grd = wheel_context.createLinearGradient(1, 0, can_w, can_h);
```

Other errors you can consider looking at:

- You are declaring the variables twice - the first var line in the example code is unnecessary
- You are reading *CSS* size of canvas *element*, not its bitmap size (they are not the same).

To read proper dimension of canvas (unless you intended to read the CSS size for some reason) you need to use the following instead:

```
var can_w = wheel_canvas.width;  //$(wheel_canvas).width();
var can_h = wheel_canvas.height; //$(wheel_canvas).height();
```

or if you insist on using jQuery:

```
var can_w = $(wheel_canvas).prop('width');
var can_h = $(wheel_canvas).prop('height');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is superb. Four arguments exactly the answer to begin it running on chrome. Yet i have to open another question. About getting image data. If I draw an image on canvas which is 2nd part of above code. I still get same error even when i really dont have cross-origin images

Comment: @Sami I don't see any image related code (drawImage) in the example? But in general, if you load the image directly from local disk (file:///, or local path) then it would be considered cors as well. If this happens on your local machine and you're not running a local server then that explains the cause. To solve just install and run from a local (light-weight) server (so you can use localhost://).

Answer (score 1):

For testing, you can also use `--allow-file-access-from-files` as a command-line argument to Chrome; this will allow you to use local files.